# Error when reading from two files

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to read data from two files, so I combine them into one file first.

On the line

```
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of
type 'double'.

Error in SP04C1 (line 21)
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
```

This code works fine when reading from a single text file so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
DELIMITER = '\t';
%HEADERLINES = 0;

% Import the file

system('copy SP04C1.txt+SP04C1a.txt SP04C1all.txt')

newData1 = importdata('SP04C1all.txt', DELIMITER);

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
```

The files and code are all in the same folder.

Comment: Fieldnames is only available for structs, it seems you imported a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining two files by calling to system's `copy file1 + file2 file3` will automatically create an additional ASCII code `SUB` (#26) at the end of `file3` which may cause errors when you process `file3` later. The `SUB` is kind of "soft"-indicator for end-of-file.

Comment: Thanks this must be it